# Enforcing cascading deletes Across a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've searched Stackoverflow and elsewhere but was unable to resolve this problem.

Problem: When attempting to destroy an instance variable via a Rails destroy action, I receive the error message in this post's title.

Relevant Code:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :describes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :descriptors, through: :describes, source: :metadatum
end

class Metadatum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :describes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :descriptees, through: :describes, source: :company

  ...
end

class Describe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :metadatum
end

class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def destroy
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @company.destroy
    redirect_to companies_url
  end

  ...
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: <some version #) do

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_companies_on_name", unique: true
  end

  create_table "describes", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.integer  "metadatum_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_describes_on_company_id"
    t.index ["metadatum_id"], name: "index_describes_on_metadatum_id"
  end

  create_table "metadata", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_metadata_on_name", unique: true
  end

end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :companies, :name, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateMetadata < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :metadata do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :metadata, :name, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateDescribes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :describes, id: false do |t|
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true
      t.references :metadatum, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The 'CreateDescribes' migration file sets the 'create_table' 'id' option to 'false', since I will never need direct access to the 'describes' join table. I located a Stackoverflow post (the link escapes me) where it was suggested that enforcing a cascading delete operation requires that join table entries have unique identifiers. The conventional Rails way to enforce unique database table records is to have a single primary key that is named 'id' by default. I tried implementing this recommendation by removing the 'id: false' key/value pair in the 'CreateDescribes' migration file and ensuring the 'describes' table in the schema.rb file reflected this after rerunning 'db:migrate'.

Unfortunately, this approach yielded the same error. The Rails server log identifies the following line of code in the 'CompaniesController' 'destroy' action as the source of this error:

```
@company.destroy
```

The error message generated is:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? to_s
```

When I created a new 'Company' object and saved its corresponding record to the database, I confirmed its existence, for example, by cross-checking the 'id' value in the 'params' hash against the 'id' field in the database table's record.

The 'CompaniesController' 'create' action associates a set of Metadatum objects to the new Company object by way of has_many through association between the Company and Metadatum models.

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_attributes)

  params[:metadata][:ids].each do |m|
    if !m.empty?
      @company.descriptors << Metadatum.find(m)
    end
  end

  if @company.save

  ...
end
```

I confirmed that the association is captured.

Interestingly, when I do not associate Metadatum objects with a new Company object, I am later able to destroy the Company object successfully. Only when I associate Metadatum objects to a Company object do I later encounter this error.

The error indicates the destroy action is attempted on a nil class. As I confirmed the Company object being destroyed exists, it can't be nil. What is the Rails Server log identifying as the nil class? More importantly, why does not a destroy action on a Company object with associated Metadatum objects propagate the enforced cascading deletes on the appropriate 'describes' join table?

Answer (score 0):

A response to this problem that I received elsewhere lead to a solution. First, I needed to add the 'dependent: :destroy' constraint to the 'has_many through' associations in the 'Company' and 'Metadatum' models.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :describes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :descriptors, through: :describes, source: :metadatum, dependent: :destroy
...

class Metadatum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :describes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :descriptees, through: :describes, source: :company, dependent: :destroy
...
```

Second, I needed to stick with the Rails convention of allowing the 'create_table' method to automatically generated an 'id' primary key. So, with respect to the 'describes' table in the database schema, I implemented the following steps:

Step 01: Remove the 'id: false' constraint from the appropriate migration file.

```
class CreateDescribes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    # create_table :describes, id: false do |t|
    create_table :describes do |t|
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true
      t.references :metadatum, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Step 02: Rebuild the generated database and then re-run the migration.

```
rails db:reset
rails db:migrate
```

Warning: 'rails db:reset' purges the database. Since I seeded the database with test data, I am not concerned with this at the moment. However, it does become problematic if you are further into development and the 'seed.rb' file alone is insufficient for recreating your test state.

Now, the 'describes' table in 'schema.rb' reads properly:

```
create_table "describes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "metadatum_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_describes_on_company_id"
  t.index ["metadatum_id"], name: "index_describes_on_metadatum_id"
end
```

When testing the app, the cascading delete occurs, and the appropriate 'describes' table records are deleted.